# Attaching a process to a debug session: empty process list

Tags: java, c, debugging, java-native-interface, eclipse-cdt

- Windows xp sp3
- Eclipse Junu with CDT

I've been trying to debug a JNI project using the process attachment feature.
At first, I fire the Java program, and then, when I fire the C program, I suppose to choose the javaw.exe process.

[The tutorial I used for JNI debugging](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DebuggingJNICAndJavaCodeInEclipse)

The problam is, when I suppose to choose the right process, the process list seem to be empty:
[image: Empty List]

Here is my debug configuration:
[image: Debug Configuration]

What can I do? Should I replace the debugger?

Thanks in advance,
Mark.

Comment: I suppose you have to enter the <pid> of the process to attach to  here. Get the right one by for example using the Windows Taks Manager. You might need to enable it to show the process' pid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered this problem using eclipse CDT plugin in Eclipse Juno on windows. Using sysinternals process monitor I discovered that eclipse was looking for a class file:

```
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.cdt.core.win32.x86_64_5.2.0.201209170703\org\eclipse\cdt\internal\core\win32\ProcessList.class
```

but not finding it (Eclipse is installed on my system in C:\Program Files\eclipse). The missing class file is present in the jar file:

```
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.cdt.core.win32_5.3.0.201209170703.jar
```

I am not sure why eclipse can't find the file in the jar. I copied the entire "org" directory tree out of the `org.eclipse.cdt.core.win32_5.3.0.201209170703` jar into the file system. Having done that, eclipse can now find the file

```
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.cdt.core.win32.x86_64_5.2.0.201209170703\org\eclipse\cdt\internal\core\win32\ProcessList.class
```

(and other files in that jar) and the process pick list is now populated.

Comment: what do you mean by "into the file system".

Comment: As I said above, the Eclipse process was looking for the file

Comment: Do what you need to to get the entire org tree out of the jar file mentioned above such that the files in the org tree can be found in the C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.cdt.core.win32.x86_64_5.2.0.201209170703 directory. You may need to create the org.eclipse.cdt.core.win32.x86_64_5.2.0.201209170703 directory. Use "jar" command, 7zip, or some tool to access the jar contents and place them "in the file system" (not merely archived in a jar in the file system).

Comment: You extract the org directory from the jar into a directory called  C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.cdt.core.win32.x86_64_5.2.0.201209170703 such that you have  C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.cdt.core.win32.x86_64_5.2.0.201209170703\org etc. when done. (The C:\Program Files\eclipse part depends on your eclipse installation location).

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work for me. I was able to find the jar and extract the jar, but still got the same error.

I switch back to Eclipse v3.7 (Indigo) with CDT and everything works. Same GCC toolchain and project, all I did was change which version of eclipse I was using and the attach to process works fine. I'll report the bug to CDT team but Juno is really costing me some man hours (both for CPP and Java...)

Good luck other CDT users!

UPDATE:

I was able to get your workaround to work. I extracted the specified jar and it came out as a 'org' directory in the plugin folder. But really, it needed to be extracted in the directory/folder that has the same name as the Jar. This is strange...

Well, Juno+CDT is working again.. guess I shouldn't be such a hater ;-)