# Attaching a process to a debug session: javaw.exe is not shown

Tags: java, c, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-juno

followed the steps mentioned in the following thread,

[Attaching a process to a debug session: empty process list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123019/attaching-a-process-to-a-debug-session-empty-process-list)

Now I am able to get the process list. But Process list is missing "javaw.exe" which is shown in the task manager.

any help?

Comment: Enter ths process id of the process you want to attacht to. You can get the process id from by looking for the process's image name in the task manager.

Comment: When I am entering the process ID, the OK button is getting disabled

Comment: Got it working in Kepler..havent tried it in Juno..but Program with PID can be see in the process list. Selected that program and it started working. Thanks Alk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first had this problem but found the process under the name "Program". Take note of the executable name.

[image: Eclipse attach to process dialog]

Answer (score 2):

Enter the process id of the process you want to attach to.

You can get the process id by looking for the process's image name in the task manager.